# How to add a shortcut (Mnemonics) to a JMenuItem

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an 'about' JMenuItem that when clicked displays a text box of what the application does. I'd like the user to be able to access this via a shortcut (mnemonic). This is my current code. (I have already tried numerous times I just thought it would be better to post the code with no errors).

```
 JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("About", new ImageIcon("aboutIcon.gif"));
    m1.add(item2);

    item2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This application converts numerous values"
                    + " of different formats"
                    + " inputted by the user, and displays the desired "
                    + "result.\n Author: James Cordiner"
                    + "\n© Copyright");

        }

    });
```

Comment: Did you try `item2.setAccelerator(...)`?

Comment: Do you want a mnemonic, or an accelerator? They are different. The mnemonic lets you select menu items via key presses (not the mouse); an accelerator allows selection using a key combination without ever opening the menu. So use `setMnemonic()` or `setAccelerator()`,depending on what you really want.

Comment: Well at the minute, the user has to click file, then about and the textbox appears. I'd like them to just click alt-A and the textbox appears, what do you recommend? Sorry just realised how obvious that is, thankyou I'll look them up!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about an accelerator. Use
`item2.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( KeyEvent.VK_A, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK) );`

However, when using the ALT key you might run afoul of the mnemonic initiator of the current look-and-feel. For example, if some main menu item has a mnemonic of 'A', hitting ALT+A will select that menu item rather than the one you want. It is probably better to use CTRL instead of ALT.